# Is PHP session retained through intervening PHP pages executed on the server?

Tags: php, session, cookies

Sorry, this seems pretty basic, but I cannot find a definitive answer and am not well-versed enough in PHP sessions to know if this is obvious.

Suppose I have 3 PHP pages. The usual client behavior is to visit page1.php, then submit a post to page2.php.  page2.php runs, and then passes the user back to page1.php or on to page3.php.
page2.php is a script on the server that does not send anything to the browser. And page2.php does not need anything in the session.

If I have session_start() only on page1.php and page3.php, will the session get lost moving through page2.php? Thanks!

Comment: I suspect tahat the session will be fine. In the couple of minutes you've waited for this comment you could have set it up and tried it.

Comment: As default when you start a session, there is a session cookie sent to the browser, which the browser then send with each request to the server, until that cookie expires (which by default are after being idle for x amount of minutes or when the browser is closed), no matter which route it takes to get to those pages. And even on page2.php, your server do send a response back to the browser (which is where the actual redirect happens), so there is still request/response, even if the server doesn't send any _body_ back for the browser to display, which is irrelevant for sessions.

Comment: I wonder at those comments I see on stackoverflow berating the proposer of the question that they should have googled an answer or seen it elsewhere, or just tried it.  But it goes to the purpose of stackoverflow.  For my question, thank you M. Eriksson, your comment helps my understanding.  And so, inferring from your comment, my question is answered as: "No, unless the session expires, the intervening page2.php will not mess up the session status, it does not have to include a session_start."